# JTable/setDefaultRenderer Multiple Selected Rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, background-color

I have searched literally all over the Internet and could not find a working solution to my problem.

I have a `JTable`, to which I want to dynamically change the background colors of **multiple rows** without affecting the background color of the other rows which colors might have already been altered.

The color change is triggered by an `actionListener` on a `JMenuItem` of a `ContextMenu`, as shown in the follwowing:

[image]

The code that I tried so far is as follows:

```java
    JMenu highlightMenu = new JMenu("Highlight");

    // Add null
    for (Color color : Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA,
        Color.PINK, Color.GRAY)) {
      JMenuItem x = new JMenuItem();
      x.setOpaque(true);
      x.setBackground(color);

      highlightMenu.add(x);

      x.addHierarchyListener(e -> x.setText(tab.getTable()
          .getValueAt(tab.getTable().getSelectedRow(), tab.getTable().getColumn("Server").getModelIndex()).toString()));

      x.addActionListener(e -> IntStream.of(tab.getTable().getSelectedRows())
          .forEach(row -> ((Component) tab.getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 0)).setBackground(color)));

      // x.addActionListener(e -> {
      // IntStream.of(tab.getTable().getSelectedRows())
      // .forEach(r -> tab.getTable().setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new
      // DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
      // @Override
      // public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      // boolean isSelected,
      // boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
      // Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
      // isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

      // if (r == row) {
      // comp.setBackground(color);
      // } else {
      // comp.setBackground(null);
      // }

      // return comp;
      // }
      // }));

      // tab.getTable().repaint();
      // });
    }
```

If anyone has a working solution, please share it, would be really appreciated!

**EDIT 0**: I cleaned-up the edits as they were too numerous, so I added debugging strings and this table is not behaving as it should at all, please see the following screenshot:

[image]

Note: Also not sure why but it seems that the table is iterated mutliple times (5) as shown in the above output, this should not be the case as each `JMenuItem` has its own event listener... And it should be triggered only once depending on which color/JMenuItem is picked...

And the resulting table:

[image]

From the following code:

```java
    for (Color color : Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA,
        Color.PINK, Color.GRAY)) {
      JMenuItem x = new JMenuItem();
      x.setOpaque(true);
      x.setBackground(color);
      x.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

      highlightMenu.add(x);

      x.addHierarchyListener(e -> x.setText(tab.getTable()
          .getValueAt(tab.getTable().getSelectedRow(), tab.getTable().getColumn("Server").getModelIndex()).toString()));

      x.addActionListener(e -> {
        IntStream.of(tab.getTable().getSelectedRows()).forEach(row -> this.highlightedRows.put(row, color)
        // this.highlightedRows.put(row, Arrays.asList(Color.BLACK, color)
        );

        tab.getTable().setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
          @Override
          public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
              boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component component = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            stdOut.println(String.format("%s -> %s", row, highlightedRows.get(row)));

            if (highlightedRows.get(row) != null) {
              stdOut.println("XXXXXXX");
              component.setBackground(highlightedRows.get(row));
            }

            // if (!isSelected && highlightedRows.containsKey(row)) {
            // component.setForeground(highlightedRows.get(row).get(0));
            // component.setBackground(highlightedRows.get(row).get(1));
            // }

            return component;
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

As you see something is not right there...

EDIT N: Almost solved this issue with the following code:

```java
    for (Color color : Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA,
        Color.PINK, Color.GRAY)) {
      final JMenuItem x = new JMenuItem();
      x.setOpaque(true);
      x.setBackground(color);
      x.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

      highlightMenu.add(x);

      x.addHierarchyListener(e -> x.setText(tab.getTable()
          .getValueAt(tab.getTable().getSelectedRow(), tab.getTable().getColumn("Server").getModelIndex()).toString()));

      x.addActionListener(e -> {
        IntStream.of(tab.getTable().getSelectedRows())
            .forEach(row -> this.highlightedRows.put(row, Arrays.asList(Color.BLACK, color)));
        // row -> this.highlightedRows.put(row, color)

        tab.getTable().setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
          @Override
          public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
              boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            final Component component = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row,
                column);

            stdOut.println(String.format("%s -> %s", row, highlightedRows.get(row)));

            if (highlightedRows.containsKey(row)) {
              component.setForeground(highlightedRows.get(row).get(0));
              component.setBackground(highlightedRows.get(row).get(1));
            } else {
              if (row % 2 == 0) {
                component.setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getColor("Table.background"));
              } else {
                component
                    .setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getColor("Table.alternateRowColor"));
              }

              component.setForeground(javax.swing.UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getColor("Table.foreground"));
            }

            if (isSelected) {
              component
                  .setForeground(javax.swing.UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getColor("Table.selectionForeground"));
              component
                  .setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getColor("Table.selectionBackground"));
            }

            return component;
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

The only thing now is that the event listener is called more than once, see previous EDIT, whilst this addressed then this would be 100% solved, thanks all!

Comment: The row color is going to have to be a property of each cell in the tow, so it can extracted by the renderer

Comment: @MadProgrammer do you please gave a code snippet/example on how to achieve this?

Comment: You need to set a table cell renderer on all cells. You can't just change the background colour.

Comment: @aress31 Do you create the `Map` multiple times? There should be only one instance of that `highlightedRows` map per table. Make sure this instance exists until the table is destroyed. You should set the default renderer only once (i.e. not within the `ActionListener` code).

Comment: I just saw that you create the `Map` instance within the `for` loop. This will create a new instance per color. Then you override the table's default renderer to use the latest Map instance. I don't know the rest of the code, but it might be a good idea to make `highlightedRow` an instance member.

Comment: @aress31 See my updated answer

Comment: @majusebetter I made the HashMap a class field rather than instantiating a new one each time the `eventAction` is triggered and it is now working just fine. A last issue remains though, the untouched/unselected rows are all unstyled, no branded row, how could I please fix this?

Comment: Your renderer is not complete. For example you lose the default settings of the table because you always assume each row has a custom background. You should only reset the background if a Color instance is found in your map or the row is not selected. Also your renderer is only for columns with "String" values. Columns with other data are not affected. See; [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for an approach that will apply the highlighting to all columns.

Comment: @aress31 See updated answer - added condition (only apply color if not selected and there is a color found in the map for the specified row index).

Comment: @majusebetter please see last edit.

Comment: The same renderer is used for all rows so it keeps the last Color used. You need to reset the default background. I guess you didn't look at the example code I provided to you in my previous comment.

Comment: @camickr I looked at all replies/responses and it should not be the case since I have put a condition that targets only selected rows, if (highlightedRows.get(row) != null) if it returns false, it should return the raw/untouched component, makes no sense!

Comment: @camickr, I look at table row rendering but I dont think it is applicable to the way I constructed my app, see https://github.com/aress31/swurg/tree/dev

Comment: *I look at table row rendering but I dont think it is applicable* - it is if you want all the columns to be highlighted. Currently your first column is not highlighted. The concept of using the Map would also need to be implemented as you did here.

Comment: @camickr if you take a look at the repo I linked you would understand why I believe that it is not appliceable, the table is defined/instantiated and populated in another class, from this object with the event listener I cannot override it AFAIK,

Comment: Well, that is your current design. All the logic related to the table could be in a single class. In the simple [mre] below all the code is in one class. If you are letting your IDE generate the code then you won't learn how to code a GUI effectively. The IDE should just be used to help debug etc.

Comment: @camickr who said that the code is generated entirely by my IDE? I actually designed it from bottom up, I am just not a career dev, more of a hobbyist.

Comment: Then I don't understand your comment saying you "cannot override it"? That makes no sense since you were given working examples that demonstrates it can be done. If you wrote all the code on your own you can do whatever you want. All you need to do is restructure your code.

Comment: This code extends/implements third party interface and therefore I am directed in my implementation choices, anyway not going to enter in an argument about that, at the end of the day it is irrelavant, thanks for your help @camickr. A PR would be welcome if you fancy. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep a map which maps row indices to colors and use it in your default renderer. In the action listener you just need to put the row index with the assigned color into this map.

```
final Map<Integer, Color> highlightedRows = new HashMap<>();
highlightedRows.put(1, Color.GREEN);
highlightedRows.put(2, Color.YELLOW);
    
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
        
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        final var cmp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        final var color = highlightedRows.get(row);
        if (color != null && !isSelected) {
            cmp.setBackground(color);
        }
        return cmp;
    }
});
```

**Result**

[image]

**EDIT: Fully working example**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class TableRowHighlightExample {

    private final Map<Integer, Color> highlightedRows = new HashMap<>();

    private JTable table;

    private JPopupMenu createHighlightMenu() {
        final JPopupMenu highlightMenu = new JPopupMenu();

        final Color[] colors = { 
                Color.RED, 
                Color.ORANGE, 
                Color.YELLOW, 
                Color.GREEN, 
                Color.BLUE, 
                Color.MAGENTA,
                Color.PINK, 
                Color.GRAY 
        };
                
        // Add null
        for (final Color color : colors) {
            final JMenuItem x = new JMenuItem();
            x.setOpaque(true);
            x.setBackground(color);

            highlightMenu.add(x);

            x.addActionListener(e -> {
                final int[] selectedRows = this.table.getSelectedRows();
                for (final int row : selectedRows) {
                    highlightedRows.put(row, color);
                }
            });
        }
        
        return highlightMenu;
    }

    private JTable createTable() {
        final String[] colNames = { "Column 0" };
        final Object[][] data = { { "Row 0" }, { "Row 1" }, { "Row 2" }, { "Row 3" } };

        final var table = new JTable(data, colNames);
        table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        table.setComponentPopupMenu(this.createHighlightMenu());
        
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                
                final var cmp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                cmp.setBackground(highlightedRows.get(row));
                return cmp;
            }
        });
        
        return table;
    }

    public void run() {
        final var frame = new JFrame();
        this.table = this.createTable();
        
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(this.table));
        frame.setSize(500, 200);        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableRowHighlightExample().run();
    }
}
```

[image]